# EETypeLoadException in AudioBuffer.CreateReference()

Tags: uwp

I'm doing some audio capturing based on scenario 3 of [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation), and noticed that an `EETypeLoadException` is shown in the Output:

```
Exception thrown at 0x753296C2 in AudioCreation.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EETypeLoadException at memory location 0x11BFD8C4.
```

Every time this line is executed (see line 97 of [this sample file](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/AudioCreation/cs/AudioCreation/Scenario3_FrameInputNode.xaml.cs)):

```
using (IMemoryBufferReference reference = buffer.CreateReference())
```

What is the cause of the `EETypeLoadException` and do I need to worry about this?

---

**Edit**

Steps to reproduce:

1. Download [Windows-universal-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples)
2. Open the Windows-universal-samples\Samples\AudioCreation\cs\AudioCreation.sln solution
3. Open AudioCreation project properties > Debug > Set debugger types to "Mixed (Managed and Native)
4. Run the app in debug mode
5. Click on option 3 "Using a FrameInputNode"
6. Click on the "Generate Audio" button
7. Look in the Output > Debug window, where I'm getting the `EETypeLoadExceptions`

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, Update 3

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue in my side. Could you please share detailed  reproducible steps?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Added repro steps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the cause of the EETypeLoadException and do I need to worry about this?

This is a known issue, the `EETypeLoadException` will be thrown when trying to call `AudioBuffer.CreateReference` and assign to a variable:

```
using (AudioBuffer buffer = frame.LockBuffer(AudioBufferAccessMode.Write))
using (IMemoryBufferReference reference = buffer.CreateReference()) //Here
{
}
```

It's trying to load type information for the class that `CreateReference` returns but cannot find it.

**In UWP apps, you can ignore this exception especially in Mixed debug mode. In Desktop application, like WPF, we may add a CAST to avoid such exception.**